# jQuery: Why does my animated p "jump"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm making a simple animation in jQuery, when you hover an a, the p element slides into place underneath it (position: absolute;) but when you hover the a, the p jumps to a position then animates, it's so weird!

```
$(".wrap a").hover(function() {
    $(".wrap p").animate({left: '0'},{duration:500});
            }, function(){        
                $(".wrap p").animate({left: '100%'}, {duration:500});
    });
;
```

Any ideas why this might happen?

[View it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/BAXc2/1/)

Comment: It seems to work fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed `0` instead of `0%`, it will confuse jQuery in some browsers where `getComputedStyle` (what jQuery uses) behaviour differs in units.

http://jsfiddle.net/BAXc2/3/

Answer (score 4):

Simply write '0%' instead of 0.

```
$(".wrap a").hover(function() {
    $(".wrap p").animate({left: '0%'},{duration:500});
            }, function(){        
                $(".wrap p").animate({left: '100%'}, {duration:500});
    });
```